# Error 404 Pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, redirect

I want to set up a broken link reporting in my custom 404 page. I want to make the document a php page, so I can capture and send the url that was requested, to my email. I have some very basic php code in it so far to send the email, so I got that. The problem is, how to I make the 404 page apear on the actual broken link page, not redirect it to the 404 page. E.g. You see Google's website has it to where if you find a broken link like this (https://www.google.com/asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf) then it stays on that same page and echos the requested uri. How do they do that? I just use the .htaccess method like

> `ErrorDocument 404 http://mydomain.domain/404`

But this redirects the 404 page to there. How do I make the 404 apear on the actual broken link page (non-existing page)?

Comment: btw, `http://mydomain.domain/404` that 404 is interpreted as a folder, not a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the full url use a relative one - this will make it work as expected

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.php
```

a full url will cause a redirect as specified in the manual:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html

Comment: So, how do I assign an hidden imput to have the value of the requested uri?

Comment: I have this code... `<p>The page you were looking for 
could not be found.</p>
<p>The requested url is: <?php $requested = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; echo $requested; ?></p>
<a class="button" href="/">Back to homepage</a>
<input type="hidden" name="message" value="<?php $requested; ?>"></input>
<a class="button" href="">Report broken link</a>`

Comment: never mind, I got it using php :D

Comment: @BlackVikingPro great glad it works please learn how to accpet answers on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers